# XDebug: How to retain hooks during remotely-initiated debug session?

Tags: xdebug

In an XAMPP/Linux environment, I'm using XDebug via Eclipse to assist set-up of a new application.

I start the application from the client laptop like so:

```
http://192.168.1.5/oc/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START
```

(The idea being that I can *step* on the server while *interact* via the physically adjacent client.)

I can successfully monitor execution up to the point where I see the initial panel on the browser.

I now wish to pause execution immediately a button is clicked...

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="primary" value="Finish setup" data-finishing="Finishing …">
</form>
```

The *submit* no doubts triggers re-execution of 'index.php' but the debug hook is seemingly lost. (The break points are ignored.)

How can I retain (or re-establish) the hook?

**NB:**
Problem is only because I am debugging remotely. I see expected behaviour when I commence monitoring via *Eclipse -> Debug As* issued server-side.

Here's the full **.ini**:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s
```

Comment: Just use Xdebug extension for browser: when activated, it will setup Xdebug cookie (instead of you adding `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START` to the URL). This way it will work with all requests in the same session, even AJAX ones (as long as they sent to the same domain, of course).

Comment: Other options are: 1) Use `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini -- it will tell Xdebug to attempt to debug *every single request*. 2) You can also do a programmatic breakpoint -- will also trigger debug session if not started. For that  put `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code. Downside -- you need to edit PHP code.

Comment: P.S. Having `xdebug.profiler_enable = 1` while debugging makes no sense at all, especially having it enabled all the time like you have. Better trigger it when needed (Xdebug browser extensions can also do that).

Comment: @LazyOne Got it. Much obliged. I should have studied  [this](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) beforehand.